# No internet connection when trying to install Arch linux in qemu

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, arch-linux, qemu

I'm trying to slowly switch from windows to linux. So I thought that it will be good idea to install arch on VM. Since I learned about VM's I was using VirtualBox but now I wanted to try qemu, because I saw comparsion on the internet and it showed me that qemu is faster. I installed it with QtEmu gui (so it will be easier for me).  [Here's an image of my VM settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBpoF.png)

Now the problem is that after booting I try to check if I have internet connection with `ping 8.8.8.8` and `ping wp.pl` but nothing shows up. [What my VM looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDYsi.png)

Maybe the problem is in the processor type I choose? I use Ryzen 7 2700x, first i tried base - didn't work, then AMD Athlon - didn't work, and now kvm64 because it is working.

Is there any way to fix this internet problem? I'm newbie so I would be very pleased if somebody couuld explain to me why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to try qemu, because I saw comparsion on the internet and it showed me that qemu is faster.

With hardware virtualization, practically there might be *not much* of a difference. The two programs do emulate different hardware and peripherals (e.g. different virtual GPUs), but the "basic" CPU virtualization is outsourced to your physical CPU either way.

However, in your screenshot, Qemu is set up *without* hardware virtualization – it is using software emulation only (the "Tiny Code Generator (TCG)" mode). This is going to be *much* slower than even VirtualBox's no-virt mode.

Qemu on Windows has two options for hardware virtualization: either Intel HAXM (which is for Intel CPUs only) or Windows Hypervisor Platform (the same that Hyper-V uses). With an AMD CPU, you can't use HAXM so you will need to install [the WHP feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249419/i-have-got-an-amd-ryzen-cpu-and-android-emulator-doesnt-work).

(Both HAXM and WHP are roughly equivalent to KVM on Linux.)

Note that installing WHP (or HAXM) will also prevent VirtualBox from using its own hardware virtualization driver. Now VirtualBox can also use WHP, but it's slower than native VirtualBox kernel driver. (Actually, it's almost as if VirtualBox deliberately runs slower when using WHP...)

> Maybe the problem is in the processor type I choose? I use Ryzen 7 2700x, first i tried base - didn't work, then AMD Athlon - didn't work, and now kvm64 because it is working.

It is *very* unlikely that this would have anything to do with networking.

> Is there any way to fix this internet problem? I'm newbie so I would be very pleased if somebody couuld explain to me why it doesn't work.

There are quite a few things to check before the problem can be determined.

1. Does the VM detect a (virtual) Ethernet card? Run `ip link` and look for interfaces named `eth#` or `en###`. If there are none, try configuring Qemu to emulate a different card. Might be useful to check the VM's `dmesg -H` output for any error messages.
2. What is the virtual Ethernet card connected to? Qemu, like VirtualBox, has several networking modes: it has "SLIRP" or "user" networking (equivalent to "NAT" in VirtualBox), it has "bridged" networking, and it has a few other modes that probably won't work in Windows.

   Take a look at [this page](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking). Note that "User"/SLIRP networking mode, although it's the easiest one otherwise, might simply not be able to use `ping` at all. It could be that everything else works, you just can't ping stuff.
3. Is the shown Ethernet card *enabled* in the guest OS, that is, does 'ip link' show the `<UP>` flag next to it? The kernel does not activate network interfaces on its own; a program has to do it. The ArchISO is set up to do it automatically via 'dhcpcd', but it's always better to check instead of assuming that it "must have worked".
4. Does the Ethernet card think the physical link is working? The same 'ip link' output should show `<LOWER_UP>` if it's working, `<NO_CARRIER>` otherwise. (Of course, it's virtual, so the connection is also virtual – but e.g. VirtualBox has a "Pretend that cable is connected" checkbox...)
5. Does the Ethernet card have any IP addresses assigned? Run `ip addr` and look for addresses *other than* the "fe80::[...]" one. Specifically, you're trying to ping an IPv4 address, so the VM needs an IPv4 address too. (Again, the ArchISO is set up to automatically get an address via DHCP, but don't just assume that it happened.)

Comment: It seems like I cant't enable Hyper-V because I use Windows 10 home :(  After ip link I can see two interfaces: lo and ens3. I checked in machine options and it appears that i'm in user mode. Phisical link is working, it has up and lower_up flag. Yes, my Ethernet card has assigned ip with 24 bit mask. When I try to do pacman -Sy command stucks on: synchronizing package databases... core. Maybe this will give you some clues on what is wrong here